# Angular activatedRoute paramMap.params not known by TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I'm subscribing to `this.activatedRoute.paramMap` which according to TS is of type ParamMap. This is all nice but when I'm debugging it seems to have this convenient property `paramMap.params` which I can use like this

```
.subscribe((paramMap: any) => {
  const { projectId, domainId, chapterId, unitId } = paramMap.params;
});
```

However, this `params` property is not known to exist on ParamMap according to TS so I need to cast it.
What is going on here? Am I doing this wrong?

[image]

In DevTools I'm seeing "ParamsAsMap" but this is not a known type I can cast to. I'm not even sure where this is coming from, Google search turns blank, where does DevTools even get this from?

Comment: That's not part of the interface available in the subscription, whether or not it's on the runtime object: https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute#paramMap -> https://angular.io/api/router/ParamMap

Answer (score 0):

`params` property of ParamsMap is defined [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/59680c2644456f9d48b78e713f7f225dfb5bb289/packages/router/src/shared.ts#L70)

Like @jonrsharpe mentioned, it is defined on the object itself,

```
.subscribe((paramMap) => {
     console.log(paramMap.[<yourQueryParamKey>])
});
```

The type of `paramMap` is [Params](https://angular.io/api/router/Params#params),
So actually decoupling the type is:
`.subscribe((paramMap: [key: string]: any) => ...`

`[key: string]: any` correlates with everything (including `params` property) so this is actually typed

Comment: Don't you mean "The type of `paramMap.params` is Params, which is a private property"?

Comment: `activatedRoute.params` uses Params, but might be deprecated in the future [-> link](https://angular.io/guide/router#activated-route)

Comment: No I don’t, notice that in the source code